# Setting up Mozilla JetPack "The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value"

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am getting the below error ...

```
D:\Setups\Mozilla JetPack SDK\bin>activate.bat
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jetpack_sdk_env
(D:\Setups\Mozilla JetPack SDK\bin) D:\Setups\Mozilla JetPack SDK\bin>
```

Whats wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: also what version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: System is Windows 7 x64, Python 2.7.1 (does it matter? JetPack says it supports 2.5/6, I am thinking maybe 2.7 should work?), SDK is 1.0b4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one thing, try not to use spaces in file or folder names, that can mess things up.

Comment: System is Windows 7 x64, Python 2.7.1 (does it matter? JetPack says it supports 2.5/6, I am thinking maybe 2.7 should work?), SDK is 1.0b4. I also tried without spaces "D:\Setups\JetPack\bin\activate.bat" got the same error

Comment: oh I think I should be running from the JetPack dir like `D:\Setups\JetPack > bin\activate.bat` which still gives me `ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.` but I can still do `bin\cfx.bat`

Comment: ... but I think with the `activate.bat` working incorrectly, I cannot run cfx.bat from any other directory? eg `D:\Projects\JetPack-Test > cfx.bat init` or `D:\Projects\JetPack-Test > D:\Setups\JetPack\bin\cfx.bat` gives `python: can't open file '\bin\cfx': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`